# error invalid suffix Ui64 on integer constant

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw

I'm trying to build and run the [log4z library](https://github.com/zsummer/log4z). I'm using Windows 8.1 and MinGW with gcc version 4.8.1.

This is a part of the code of **log4z.cpp**

```
#include "log4z.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>


#ifdef WIN32
#include <io.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <process.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi")
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#endif

...

#ifdef WIN32
        FILETIME ft;
        GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(&ft);
        unsigned long long now = ft.dwHighDateTime;
        now <<= 32;
        now |= ft.dwLowDateTime;
        now /=10;
        now -=11644473600000000Ui64;
        now /=1000;
        pLog->_time = now/1000;
        pLog->_precise = (unsigned int)(now%1000);

...
```

When I build the project with CMake and "MinGW Makefiles" generator and compile it, I get the following error:

```
$ mingw32-make
Scanning dependencies of target log4z_win32
[ 25%] Building CXX object g++/CMakeFiles/log4z_win32.dir/__/log4z.cpp.obj
C:\Users\Fenix\Desktop\log4z\log4z.cpp:1219:9: error: invalid suffix "Ui64" on integer constant
   now -=11644473600000000Ui64;
         ^
g++\CMakeFiles\log4z_win32.dir\build.make:53: recipe for target 'g++/CMakeFiles/log4z_win32.dir/__/log4z.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [g++/CMakeFiles/log4z_win32.dir/__/log4z.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:74: recipe for target 'g++/CMakeFiles/log4z_win32.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [g++/CMakeFiles/log4z_win32.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

But, I have a virtual machine with Ubuntu 13.10 and gcc version 4.8.1  and it works!

My question is, do I need any flag to indicate it to the compiler? do I need to include any library?

Comment: maybe this helps... https://www.google.de/search?q=Ui64+suffix

Comment: Use the ULL suffix instead.

Comment: you need to enable c++11 : `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`. the Ui64 is a literal operator. see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Hans_Passant says, it works changing Ui64 by ULL.

```
now -=11644473600000000ULL;
```

Furthermore, I have found some information about this [C++ integer constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00a1awxf.aspx)